# MAGENTO: "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 126 Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_7589_0.MYI'; try to repair it" error

Tags: magento

I have recently having an issue in my site with magento.. First the images in front end has disappeared. so i was trying to fix the problem for this. but suddenly when i login to admin panel, the magento is throwing me this error

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 126 Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_7589_0.MYI'; try to repair it`

I am not able to find any solution for this.can anyone help me out what caused this error to show up?
 and can u also suggest me how to make the front end catalog product images visible

Comment: It's not really related to Magento but somehow your database has been messed up. Check if your disk is full. It might be the reason.

Comment: then wat about the frontend images?

Comment: Well if your disk is full, it might cause strange errors. Did you check it?

Comment: FIXED THE ERROR PROBLEM BY RESTARTING THE SERVER...THanks for ur replies

Comment: but the images are still invisible

Comment: Right click on the image, "Open Image in new tab" and see what error the webserver gives you

Comment: http://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/305x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/small_image.jpg  --- showing me this

Comment: This link is useless for me to help resolving your problem, try to click on it :)

Comment: Alternatively try emptying Magento cache

Comment: tried everything but no luck

Comment: try this, error its because of MySQL tmp folder space issue.
there is not enough space in /tmp for the temporary table, so this error will through.
I fixed this by setting “tmpdir = /home/tmp” (which has lots of space on my host) in my.cnf.
just create a folder tmp which has enough space and give tmpdir in my.cnf. ref:http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/302400/

Answer (score 5):

As stated in the comments, the error is most probably a disk space problem. There is not enough space available in the MySQL temp folder or on the whole server. I just encountered the same on my local machine and freeing some disk space and restarting the system afterwards solved the problem.

Regarding the images issue, this is always a permission issue. Check that the web server has write permissions on the `media` folder.

Answer (score 1):

If your server is ubuntu, you can execute below command to free up some space.

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

This will clean the apt cache on Ubuntu